# Swift JSON decoder couldn't find key in JSON data from Flickr

Tags: ios, json, swift

I came across a json decoding error in an example in a book. The error says:

```
    2021-05-06 07:01:31.193094+1000 Photorama[1562:29734] [] nw_protocol_get_quic_image_block_invoke dlopen libquic failed
Error fetching interesting photos: keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "photos", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "photos", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"photos\", intValue: nil) (\"photos\").", underlyingError: nil))
```

However, in the json data returned from Flickr, the key "photos" did exist. An abbreviated copy of the json data is as follows:

```
    {
  "extra": {
    "explore_date": "2021-05-04",
    "next_prelude_interval": 57778
  },
  "photos": {
    "page": 1,
    "pages": 5,
    "perpage": 100,
    "total": 500,
    "photo": [
      {
        "id": "51156301899",
        "owner": "138752302@N05",
        "secret": "31d327f54f",
        "server": "65535",
        "farm": 66,
        "title": "*the power of the sun*",
        "ispublic": 1,
        "isfriend": 0,
        "isfamily": 0,
        "datetaken": "2021-04-20 06:52:11",
        "datetakengranularity": "0",
        "datetakenunknown": "0",
        "url_z": "https://live.staticflickr.com/65535/51156301899_31d327f54f_z.jpg",
        "height_z": 380,
        "width_z": 640
      },
      "stat": "ok"
      }
```

The code of the program is as follows:
AppDelegate.swift (no changes)

```
import UIKit

@main
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {



    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }

    // MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        // Called when a new scene session is being created.
        // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
        // Called when the user discards a scene session.
        // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
        // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
    }


}
```

SceneDelegate.swift

```
import UIKit

class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
        // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
        // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).
        guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
        
        let rootViewController = window!.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
        let photosViewController = rootViewController.topViewController as! PhotosViewController
        photosViewController.store = PhotoStore()
    }

    func sceneDidDisconnect(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called as the scene is being released by the system.
        // This occurs shortly after the scene enters the background, or when its session is discarded.
        // Release any resources associated with this scene that can be re-created the next time the scene connects.
        // The scene may re-connect later, as its session was not necessarily discarded (see `application:didDiscardSceneSessions` instead).
    }

    func sceneDidBecomeActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called when the scene has moved from an inactive state to an active state.
        // Use this method to restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) when the scene was inactive.
    }

    func sceneWillResignActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called when the scene will move from an active state to an inactive state.
        // This may occur due to temporary interruptions (ex. an incoming phone call).
    }

    func sceneWillEnterForeground(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called as the scene transitions from the background to the foreground.
        // Use this method to undo the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func sceneDidEnterBackground(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called as the scene transitions from the foreground to the background.
        // Use this method to save data, release shared resources, and store enough scene-specific state information
        // to restore the scene back to its current state.
    }


}
```

PhotosViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class PhotosViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet private var imageView: UIImageView!
    var store: PhotoStore!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        // store.fetchInterestingPhotos()
        store.fetchInterestingPhotos {
            (photoResult) in
            
            switch photoResult {
            case let .success(photos):
                print("Successfully found \(photos.count) photos")
            case let .failure(error):
                print("Error fetching interesting photos: \(error)")
            }
        }
        
    }


}
```

FlickrAPI.swift

```
import Foundation

enum EndPoint: String {
    case interestingPhotos = "flickr.interestingness.getList"
}
/*
 https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.interestingness.getList
 &api_key=a6d819499131071f158fd740860a5a88&extras=url_z,date_taken
 &format=json&nojsoncallback=1
 */
struct FlickrAPI {
    private static let baseURLString = "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest"
    private static let apiKey = "a6d819499131071f158fd740860a5a88"
    
    // assemble url from baseURLString and query items
    private static func flickrURL (endPoint: EndPoint, parameters: [String: String]?) -> URL {
        var components = URLComponents(string: baseURLString)!
        var queryItems = [URLQueryItem]()
        let baseParams = [
            "method": endPoint.rawValue,
            "format": "json",
            "nojsoncallback": "1",
            "api_key": apiKey
        ]
        for (key, value) in baseParams {
            let item = URLQueryItem(name: key, value: value)
            queryItems.append(item)
        }
        if let addtionalParams = parameters {
            for (key, value) in addtionalParams {
                let item = URLQueryItem(name: key, value: value)
                queryItems.append(item)
            }
        }
        components.queryItems = queryItems
        
        return components.url!
    }
    static var interestingPhotoURL: URL {
        // url_z is a URL shortener (zipper) for convenience and beauty
        return flickrURL(endPoint: .interestingPhotos,
                         parameters: ["extras": "url_z,date_taken"])
    }
    static func photos (fromJSON data: Data) -> Result<[Photo], Error> {
        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let flickrResponse = try decoder.decode(FlickrResponse.self, from: data)
    
            return .success(flickrResponse.photosInfo.photos)
        } catch {
            return .failure(error)
        }
    }
}

struct FlickrResponse: Codable {
    //let photos: FlickrPhotosResponse
    let photosInfo: FlickrPhotosResponse
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case photosInfo = "photos"
    }
}

struct FlickrPhotosResponse: Codable {
    //let photo: [Photo]
    let photos: [Photo]
    
    enum CodingKyes: String, CodingKey {
        case photos = "photo"
    }
}
```

PhotoStore.swift

```
import Foundation

class PhotoStore {
    private let session: URLSession = {
        let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        return URLSession(configuration: config)
    }()
    
    private func processPhotosRequest (data: Data?, error: Error?) ->
    Result<[Photo], Error> {
        guard let jsonData = data else {
            return .failure(error!)
        }
        return FlickrAPI.photos(fromJSON: jsonData)
    }
    
    func fetchInterestingPhotos (completion: @escaping (Result<[Photo], Error>) -> Void) {
        let url = FlickrAPI.interestingPhotoURL
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request) {
            (data, response, error) in
            
        /*if let jsonData = data {
            if let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8) {
                print(jsonString)
            }
            } else if let requestError = error {
                print("Error fetching interest photos: \(requestError)")
            } else {
                print("Unexpect error with the request")
            }*/
            let result = self.processPhotosRequest(data: data, error: error)
            completion(result)
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Photo.swift

```
import Foundation

class Photo: Codable {
    let title: String
    let remoteURL: URL
    let photoID: String
    let dateTaken: Date
    
    public init (title: String, remoteURL: URL, photoID: String, dateTaken: Date) {
        self.title = title
        self.remoteURL = remoteURL
        self.photoID = photoID
        self.dateTaken = dateTaken
    }
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case title
        case remoteURL = "url_z"
        case photoID = "id"
        case dateTaken = "datetaken"
    }
}
```

I'd like to be advised where the problem is and how to solve it. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Try pasting your API response into app.quicktype.io and use the generated code

Comment: You are providing invalid JSON format in your question. Also, please provide only code needed to be check by others. No need to include appdelegate, scenedelegate, etc if not needed

Comment: You need to learn to read and interpret error messages, it’s not that hard most of the time and it’s a necessary knowledge for a software developer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `photos` in the json is not an array. It's an object.

Paste your json into https://app.quicktype.io in order to get the correct Codable objects.

```
// MARK: - FlickrPhotosResponse
struct FlickrPhotosResponse: Codable {
    let extra: Extra
    let photos: Photos
}

// MARK: - Extra
struct Extra: Codable {
    let exploreDate: String
    let nextPreludeInterval: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case exploreDate = "explore_date"
        case nextPreludeInterval = "next_prelude_interval"
    }
}

// MARK: - Photos
struct Photos: Codable {
    let page, pages, perpage, total: Int
    let photo: [Photo]
    let stat: String
}

// MARK: - Photo
struct Photo: Codable {
    let id, owner, secret, server: String
    let farm: Int
    let title: String
    let ispublic, isfriend, isfamily: Int
    let datetaken, datetakengranularity, datetakenunknown: String
    let urlZ: String
    let heightZ, widthZ: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, owner, secret, server, farm, title, ispublic, isfriend, isfamily, datetaken, datetakengranularity, datetakenunknown
        case urlZ = "url_z"
        case heightZ = "height_z"
        case widthZ = "width_z"
    }
}
```